# Comparing Frames of a live Feed

Tags: c#, image-processing

**My Scenario:**

I have a camera focused at a white screen, which is taking a live feed and displaying that feed in a picture box by virtue of a FrameReceived event.

I need to kick off a process to crop the image if something is inserted between the camera and the screen.

This process needs to start when the image first changes so I need to compare one frame with another to see if anything has changed.

**My Efforts**

- I have tried hashing the images and comparing them, which doesnt work as the frames are never exactly the same
- I have tried to loop through each pixel, comparing different values such as brightness, hue etc but this is too slow
- I have tried looping through with a sub sample but it is either too slow or too unreliable.
- I even tried what I like to call the "Twisted Pair Solution" where I inverted one then added them together and checking the result but this was far too complex and slow.

**My Environment**

- Visual Studio 2012 (2010 if neccessary is available)
- Ueye camera
- C#
- The images are of type System.Drawing.Bitmap

**Notes**

The biggest problem seems to be that to reliably get this result, it takes longer than we have for a reasonable frame rate, meaning that the calculation is not finished before a new frame comes in, which means that whatever variable I use to store the previous image is being overwritten before it can stop being used, and there appears to be thread after thread building up and it causes a whole lotta shakin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using some sort of image processing library , because the default .Net image processing tools are limited ,you can use an image processing library like http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/.

Than you can for example subtract image 1 from image 2, and sum the differences. If they are below a threshold (you choose the on the fits your need) they are identical.

or you can deep deeper and try this http://thecsharper.com/?p=94